How to do a good WinVerification in this game
TextMove:

package com.example.Game;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TextMove extends Application {

    private static final int TILE_SIZE = 20;
    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    private static final double INITIAL_SPEED = 0.1;
    private static final int NUM_FOODS = 5;

    private int snakeX = 0;
    private int snakeY = 0;
    private int directionX = 1;
    private int directionY = 0;
    private double speed = INITIAL_SPEED;
    private final List<BodySegment> bodySegments = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean running = false;
    private final List<Food> foods = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<Character> eatenLetters = new ArrayList<>(); // Lista literelor mâncate
    private Pane root; // Păstrăm referința către rădăcina panoului pentru acces la eticheta de mesaj

    private static class BodySegment {
        int x;
        int y;
        char letter;

        BodySegment(int x, int y, char letter) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.letter = letter;
        }
    }

    private static class Food {
        char letter;
        int x;
        int y;

        Food(char letter, int x, int y) {
            this.letter = letter;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("text_move.fxml"));
        root = loader.load(); // Salvăm referința către rădăcina panoului
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        Canvas gameCanvas = (Canvas) root.lookup("#gameCanvas");
        GraphicsContext gc = gameCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        Button startButton = (Button) root.lookup("#startButton");
        Button stopButton = (Button) root.lookup("#stopButton");
        Button increaseSpeedButton = (Button) root.lookup("#increaseSpeedButton");
        Button decreaseSpeedButton = (Button) root.lookup("#decreaseSpeedButton");
        Button resetLettersButton = (Button) root.lookup("#resetLettersButton");

        startButton.setOnAction(event -> startGame());
        stopButton.setOnAction(event -> stopGame());
        increaseSpeedButton.setOnAction(event -> increaseSpeed());
        decreaseSpeedButton.setOnAction(event -> decreaseSpeed());
        resetLettersButton.setOnAction(event -> resetLetters());

        gameCanvas.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            KeyCode key = event.getCode();
            if (key == KeyCode.UP && directionY != 1) {
                directionX = 0;
                directionY = -1;
            } else if (key == KeyCode.DOWN && directionY != -1) {
                directionX = 0;
                directionY = 1;
            } else if (key == KeyCode.LEFT && directionX != 1) {
                directionX = -1;
                directionY = 0;
            } else if (key == KeyCode.RIGHT && directionX != -1) {
                directionX = 1;
                directionY = 0;
            }
            event.consume();
        });

        gameCanvas.setFocusTraversable(true);

        initializeGame();

        new javafx.animation.AnimationTimer() {
            long lastUpdate = 0;

            public void handle(long now) {
                if (running && now - lastUpdate >= speed * 1_000_000_000) {
                    lastUpdate = now;
                    update();
                    draw(gc);
                }
            }
        }.start();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Snake Game");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void resetLetters() {
        eatenLetters.clear();
        generateFoods();
    }


    private void initializeGame() {
        snakeX = WIDTH / 2;
        snakeY = HEIGHT / 2;
        bodySegments.clear();
        eatenLetters.clear(); // Resetăm lista de litere mâncate
        generateFoods();
    }

    private void startGame() {
        running = true;
    }

    private void stopGame() {
        running = false;
    }

    private void increaseSpeed() {
        speed -= 0.1;
    }

    private void decreaseSpeed() {
        speed += 0.1;
    }

    private void generateFoods() {
        foods.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FOODS; i++) {
            int x = (int) (Math.random() * (WIDTH / TILE_SIZE)) * TILE_SIZE;
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * (HEIGHT / TILE_SIZE)) * TILE_SIZE;
            char letter = (char) ('A' + (int) (Math.random() * 26));
            foods.add(new Food(letter, x, y));
        }
    }

    private boolean hasEatenFood() {
        for (Food food : foods) {
            if (snakeX == food.x && snakeY == food.y) {
                eatenLetters.add(food.letter); // Adăugăm litera la lista literelor mâncate
                foods.remove(food);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void checkForWin() {
        StringBuilder snakeWord = new StringBuilder();
        snakeWord.append("S"); // Adăugați capul șarpelui la începutul cuvântului

        // Adăugați literele segmentelor corpului la cuvânt
        for (BodySegment segment : bodySegments) {
            snakeWord.append(segment.letter);
        }

        // Verificați dacă cuvântul format de șarpe este "JAVA"
        if (snakeWord.toString().equals("JAVA")) {
            stopGame(); // Oprim jocul
            // Afișăm un mesaj de felicitare în interfața grafică
            Label winMessageLabel = (Label) root.lookup("#winMessageLabel");
            winMessageLabel.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    private void update() {
        snakeX += directionX * TILE_SIZE;
        snakeY += directionY * TILE_SIZE;

        if (snakeX < 0) snakeX = WIDTH - TILE_SIZE;
        if (snakeX >= WIDTH) snakeX = 0;
        if (snakeY < 0) snakeY = HEIGHT - TILE_SIZE;
        if (snakeY >= HEIGHT) snakeY = 0;

        if (hasEatenFood()) {
            if (bodySegments.isEmpty()) {
                bodySegments.add(new BodySegment(snakeX, snakeY, eatenLetters.getFirst()));
            }
            bodySegments.add(new BodySegment(snakeX, snakeY, eatenLetters.getFirst())); // Adăugați segmentul la sfârșitul listei
            eatenLetters.removeFirst(); // Eliminăm prima literă mâncată, deoarece este deja asociată segmentului de corp
            generateFoods();
        }

        for (int i = bodySegments.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            bodySegments.get(i).x = bodySegments.get(i - 1).x;
            bodySegments.get(i).y = bodySegments.get(i - 1).y;
        }
        if (!bodySegments.isEmpty()) {
            bodySegments.getFirst().x = snakeX;
            bodySegments.getFirst().y = snakeY;
        }

        checkForWin(); // Verificați dacă jucătorul a câștigat
    }

    private void draw(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        // Desenarea șarpelui
        gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        gc.fillText("S", snakeX, snakeY);

        // Desenarea segmentelor corpului
        for (int i = 1; i < bodySegments.size(); i++) {
            gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            gc.fillText(String.valueOf(bodySegments.get(i).letter),

bodySegments.get(i).x, bodySegments.get(i).y); // desenează litera
asociată
}
        // Desenarea literelor mâncate după capul șarpelui
        if (bodySegments.size() > 1) {
            gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            gc.setFont(new Font(15));
            for (int i = 0; i < eatenLetters.size(); i++) {
                gc.fillText(String.valueOf(eatenLetters.get(i)), snakeX + (i + 1) * TILE_SIZE, snakeY);
            }
        }

        // Desenarea alimentelor
        gc.setFill(Color.RED);
        gc.setFont(new Font(20));
        for (Food food : foods) {
            gc.fillText(String.valueOf(food.letter), food.x, food.y);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


text_move.fxml:

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<Pane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21"

xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <Canvas fx:id="gameCanvas" height="530.0" width="800.0" />
    <Button fx:id="startButton" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="552.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Start" />
    <Button fx:id="stopButton" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="552.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stop" />
    <Button fx:id="increaseSpeedButton" layoutX="590.0" layoutY="552.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="+Viteza" />
    <Button fx:id="decreaseSpeedButton" layoutX="671.0" layoutY="552.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="-Viteza" />
    <Button fx:id="resetLettersButton" layoutX="362.0" layoutY="552.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0"

prefWidth="92.0" text="ResetLetters" />







I need to do a win for this game but I don't know how .
I try to create a field in scenebuilder in set this visible="false" and after that when I compose the word Java to display this field and to stop playing. It don't work.
And I have one more problem I have buttons and every click on button  I move the up arrow so I can move with a snake because the button is selected.
